# What can I do to get network-manager working on 20.04?

Tags: networking, network-manager

I have been unable to get `network-manager` to work since upgrading from 19.04 to 19.10, and now to 20.04 using a dist-upgrade over the previous version.

I have been working around it by issuing the command, `sudo dhclient enp3s0` which does enable networking but doesn't function with `network-manager`. I can't disable the ethernet card, nor change any of the settings of the card with network-manager. The ebook manager, calibre, gives me an error message about networking not being available, though it actually is.

Any ideas as to what I need to do? I will gladly download .deb files to reinstall things and purge what is installed (without going to the extreme of installing from scratch).

Answer (score 1):

1. this is the commands that enabling or disabling network manager:

   - `sudo service network-manager start` - starting network-manager.
   - `sudo service network-manager stop` - stops network manager.
   - `sudo service network-manager restart` - restarts network manager.
2. i recommend using the restart command to re-active the network-manager.
3. you can also try the following commands:

   - `sudo /etc/init.d/networking stop` - to stop networking.service.
   - `sudo /etc/init.d/networking start` - to start networking.service.
   - `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart` - to restart networking.service.
4. please try this commands out and see if the problem fixed.
5. please use this two commands for networking status and post it on comments:

   - `sudo systemctl status network-manager.service`
   - `ifconfig`

Comment: @jebradl - please comment the status for the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'll have to get back with the results, but your answer did give me a clue as to the problem. There is no file, 'networking' in the /etc/init.d directory.

Comment: Since the number of characters is limited, and the formatting goes to crap with a cut and paste, I've put the output of the systemctl command in a text file at https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BLNYRc-WMPtdeo_kzaXSKHPHh3iRdIkZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: hi there i asked to get access to the drive file for overlook the output and keep trying to help you solve the problem.

Comment: The key lines from the systemctl command are:
<warn> [1600748152.8967] keyfile: load: "/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/NetworkManager-USRP": failed to load connection: File permissions (100644) are insecure
<warn> [1600748152.8988] Error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate

Comment: I had tried to put a link from google drive, but I guess that it didn't work. Here's a link to the systemctl command output on dropbox. https://www.dropbox.com/s/3gqrasghzwle0lo/network-manager-systemctl-status.txt?dl=0

Comment: from the output in the link its looks like the service is active, but its look like you have two issues because of the permissions, try to run this commands with root permissions.                                              ` sudo apt update`       `sudo apt upgrade`    `sudo service network-manager restart` , if all that commands dose not work out, i recommend to reinstall the network-manager.

Comment: Your suggestions did not work. I then downloaded the .deb files for network-manager, network-manager-gnome, and network-manager-pptp so that I'd have them available for reinstallation if the network wasn't working, and purged those files and reinstalled. After purging the files, the network was still working. I reinstalled the .deb files, and I still get the same errors. So, it appears that the problem isn't with network-manager, but some other networking file(s).